# Android Studio randomly started showing: No resource identifier found for attribute 'applicationId' in package 'android'

Tags: android, android-studio

> **Update, fixed it.**
>   I read somehwere that some erros in the manifest cause Android Studio to for some reason open the generated manifest file and throw a lot of errors. I fixed it by removing an empty value in the right manifest. Thanks everyone for the help.

One day after updating my Android Studio, I started getting this error when trying to build: 
`Error:No resource identifier found for attribute 'applicationId' in package 'android'`

Since then I've had to stop developing my app because I can't find a way to fix this.
I've tried falling back to older versions of Android Studio, I've rebuilt,cleaned,cleaned the cache.

I did read somewhere that it's something about Android Studio for whatever reason overwriting my manifest with it's own generated one, which just breaks the application. Deleting it won't help, it just keeps regenerating it's own crap which creates bunch of errors. 
It generates the manifest to this folder: `app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug`

When I open the generated manifest on android studio, it basically redlines everything.

Here's the build.grade file for the app module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "emptied"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here's the project gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-beta3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here's not the manifest that I use but the one that Android Studio generates and throws errors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="emptied"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- Optional permission for Analytics to run. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> <!-- Permissions required for GCM -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <permission
        android:name="emptied.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="emptied.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:applicationId=""
        android:icon="@mipmap/typer_ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="emptied.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="emptied"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.SplashScreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="emptied.GameSelection"
            android:label="Select a Gamemode"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="emptied.ResultScreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="Aftermath"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="emptied.PracticeGame"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="Just practice typing"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name="emptied.WordsPerMInuteGame"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="Words Per Minute Gamemode"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name="emptied.NoMistakesGame"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="Make No Mistakes Gamemode"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <!-- Include the AdActivity and InAppPurchaseActivity configChanges and themes. -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.IAPTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.appinvite.PreviewActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppInvite.Preview" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.appinvite.ACTION_PREVIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <!--
Service handling Google Sign-In user revocation. For apps that do not integrate with
            Google Sign-In, this service will never be started.
        -->
        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.RevocationBoundService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.permission.REVOCATION_NOTIFICATION" />

        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.MediaIntentReceiver" />

        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.MediaNotificationService" />
        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.ReconnectionService" />
        <!--
 FirebaseMessagingService performs security checks at runtime,
             no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true"
        -->
        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.TagManagerService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.TagManagerPreviewActivity"
            android:noHistory="true" > <!-- optional, removes the previewActivity from the activity stack. -->
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="tagmanager.c.emptied" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="emptied" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!--
 Internal (not exported) receiver used by the app to start its own exported services
             without risk of being spoofed.
        -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"
            android:exported="false" />
        <!--
 FirebaseInstanceIdService performs security checks at runtime,
             no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true"
        -->
        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <provider
            android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
            android:authorities="emptied.firebaseinitprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:initOrder="100" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: where is attribute `applicationId` is defined?

Comment: show your build.gradle file of app module

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 it is defined in the for some reason automatically generated manifest file.

Comment: @AbhishekAryan I edited the question with the gradle file.

Comment: Can you also paste the root `build.gradle` ?

Comment: @StefanJM I need your Android Manifest too ?

Comment: @Dibzmania Just edited the project gradle in.

Comment: @AbhishekAryan Added the manifest that AS generates and which causes problems

Comment: @StefanJM check answer

Answer (score 0):

For Firebase integration in your Application. App required `google-services.json` 
file in your app module folder. According to me you've missing your`.json` file or package name in that .json file is different from your application package name.

Comment: I do have it, and I changed the name for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I read somehwere that some erros in the manifest cause Android Studio to for some reason open the generated manifest file and throw a lot more errors. I fixed it by removing an empty value in the right manifest. Thanks everyone for the help.